# can't git push, pull says up to date: Current branch is behind it's remote counterpart

Tags: git, github

I've been working on a feature branch. I thought I had pulled everything before I started working(still relatively sure I did). When I go to push to the remote branch I get:

```
$ git push upstream upstream/attendance-enums:attendance-enums
To git@github.com:ga-dc/garnet.git
 ! [rejected]        upstream/attendance-enums -> attendance-enums (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:ga-dc/garnet.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
```

Then I tried:

```
$ git pull upstream attendance-enums
From github.com:ga-dc/garnet
 * branch            attendance-enums -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up-to-date.
```

Basically I know that I want my latest commit to be a PR to master, but there's a merge conflict on the github end

Additionally, what started all of this was I originally did a

```
$ git push upstream attendance-enums
```

This caused a merge conflict on github. But I can't figure out how to resolve the merge conflict in the command line.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I *believe* your issue is that you are specifying a remote branch when you should be specifying a local one (when you did your push), and visa versa (when you did your pull). Try doing the following:

```
git fetch upstream
git merge upstream/attendance-enums
git push upstream attendance-enums
```

Comment: I've tried those lines so many times =(. for the merge i keep getting `warning: refname 'upstream/attendance-enums' is ambiguous.` then it says `Already up to date`

Comment: Also, if i follow the github suggestions, it dumps a whole bunch of files into my staging area to be commited. I imagine if i were able to merge correctly I could just resolve any conflicts and that would solve that piece.

Comment: i'm sorry, just an idiot! I thought my remote branch was ahead of my local, turns out the master branch was.. easy merge conflict, easy fix, thanks for the help though!